# wxPython Camera Input

Tags: python, camera, wxpython

I'm relatively new to using wxPython and was wondering if someone could tell me where I can find tutorials or texts to learn how to use it. Specially I need to know how to connect a camera to a wxPython GUI and show the input from the camera as well as store the input into a list.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should take a look on the following,

[Integration-video-capture-into-wxPython](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/OpenCV-2-1-Integration-video-capture-into-wxPython-td3281960.html)

And the package is available here: [pyopencv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyopencv)