# Display a Pygame Webcam feed into wxpanel item

Tags: python, wxpython

I've create a wxpython frame contains three buttons have a problem formatting a video onto the wxpanel

This is how im streaming the webcam.

```
#code for the stream of webcam to frame
pygame.camera.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((220,220))
cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0", (220,220))
cam.start()

while 1:
    image = cam.get_image()
    screen.blit(image,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```

Here is the code for the panel

```
self.panel  = wx.Panel(self, -1, (550, 20), (410, 500), style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
```

How do I get my cam screen into a panel.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of anyone using PyGame for a webcam inside of wxPython. Why not just show the feed in a PyGame window instead?

Alternatively, you could use openCV with wxPython for a webcam as detailed in the following links:

- http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/OpenCV-2-1-Integration-video-capture-into-wxPython-td3281960.html
- [wxPython Camera Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664394/wxpython-camera-input)
- http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Need-a-WebCam-Recorder-in-WxPython-td4577867.html

You might also be able to use the MPlayerCtrl to view a webcam feed. Here are some links on using MPlayerCtrl in wxPython:

- http://pythonhosted.org/MplayerCtrl/
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/24/wxpython-creating-a-simple-media-player/